# Telebot and message handler in python

Tags: python, telegram, telebot

I wanted to create a simple telegram bot using python telebot that would send me a random book from the list. I faced a problem when i was trying to find a way to append the list and to save these change for future usage.

I`ve tried using else statement for the function of saving the name of the book but the program was saving not the actual name of the book but the name of the button. How should i write the code for taking a book name from the message after "add" button and putting it into the list?

Here is my code:

```
import random
import telebot
from telebot import types
import pickle

bot = telebot.TeleBot('token')

try:
    with open("book_list.p", "rb") as file:
        books = pickle.load(file)
except:
    books = []


@bot.message_handler(commands=['start'])
def button_message(message):
    markup = types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(resize_keyboard=True)
    item1 = types.KeyboardButton("Вибрати")#Choose
    item2 = types.KeyboardButton("Очистити")#Clear
    item3 = types.KeyboardButton("Додати")#Add
    markup.add(item1)
    markup.add(item2)
    markup.add(item3)
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "To select a book, click 'Select'\n To add a book to the list, click 'Add' \n ", reply_markup=markup)

@bot.message_handler(content_types="text")
def message_reply(message):
    if message.text == "Choose": #Choose
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, random.choice(books))
    if message.text == "Clear": # Clear
        bot.delete_message(message.chat.id, message.message_id)
    if message.text == "Add": # Add
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Type the book name")
    else: # Should be adding a book here
        new_book = message.text
        books.append(new_book)
        try:
            with open("book_list.p", "wb") as file:
                pickle.dump(books, file)
        finally:
            bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Book has been added")
```

Comment: You left your **Private Bot Token** in your code. You should revoke it **ASAP** by talking to the [@BotFather](https://t.me/BotFather). People might abuse the token.

Answer (score 0):

The narrowest way i found is just adding some marker word to distinguish the actual book. I've just stated that you have to input your book like: "The book Name Author". Then you just check if the word "book" is in user`s message:

```
if "book" in message.text
```